# Jackson : Serialize a JSON object to multiple objects

Tags: java, arrays, json, dictionary, jackson

I'm given a string which represents a json object of type `Map<String, String>`. There is a constraint on the number of characters in one json object. I would have to convert the json object into Array of multiple json objects, if the number of characters in the JSON object exceeds the specified limit. What is the easiest and clean way of doing this using Jackson Mapper?

For example:
if this is the json object given is:

```
{
   "cfname":"Kob",
   "NAME_6":"Philharmonic Youth Orchestra",
   "NAME_5":"Pathways to Discovery: Engineering, Medicine & CSI",
   "NAME_4":"Fashion Design Camp",
   "IMAGE_URL_1":"http://res.cloudinary.com/pxxxxxx-jxxxxxx/image/upload/c_fill,h_230,w_260/v0000000000/vccrgwdekjkpdvpsrv4f.jpg",
   "IMAGE_URL_2":"http://res.cloudinary.com/pxxxxxx-jxxxxxx/image/upload/c_fill,h_230,w_260/v0000000000/wlom2u5525nyjjbttazw.jpg"
}
```

if the character count limit for one json object is 200. Then the output would be:

```
[
       {
          "cfname":"Kob",
          "NAME_6":"Philharmonic Youth Orchestra",
          "NAME_5":"Pathways to Discovery: Engineering, Medicine & CSI",
          "NAME_4":"Fashion Design Camp"
       },
       {
          "IMAGE_URL_1":"http://res.cloudinary.com/pxxxxxx-jxxxxxx/image/upload/c_fill,h_230,w_260/v0000000000/vccrgwdekjkpdvpsrv4f.jpg"
       },
       {
          "IMAGE_URL_2":"http://res.cloudinary.com/pxxxxxx-jxxxxxx/image/upload/c_fill,h_230,w_260/v0000000000/wlom2u5525nyjjbttazw.jpg"
       }
]
```

1. We can assume that the length of any key-value pair in the given json object will be less than given character count limit.
2. we should ignore whitespaces and new line characters while counting characters.

Usecase : 
   I have to add these json objects as a header to the email. Since smtp has a character limit of 1000 for each header value. I have to break it up into multiple json objects, each json object will be one header value.

Comment: Question with samples may also help you to get an answer quick

Comment: I'd eliminate the character limit.  There's no logical reason to limit the size of a single object.

Comment: You can't change the requirement!!! I have explained my use case in the question now. Have a look at it.

Comment: Well, simplest is to iterate through the elements, calculating the length of each key/value pair, plus standard JSON overhead.  Stop when you reach the limit, spit that out, then go on from there.  (Be sure to count any escapes that JSON might add for embedded quotes, etc.)

Comment: Right. That's the trivial approach. But I was looking for a solution where we can write a custom JsonSerializer or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just used the trivial approach. Here is the code snippet I wrote, useful for others for quick use:

```
int                 charCount = 11 + rcpt.length();
Map<String, String> map       = Maps.newHashMap();

for (Entry<String, String> e : mergeTags.entrySet()) {
  int cnt = charCount(e);

  if (charCount + cnt >= 987) {
    message.addHeader(TEMPLATE_MERGEVARS_HEADER, BINDER.writeValue(map));
    map = Maps.newHashMap();
    charCount = 11 + rcpt.length();
  }

  map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
  charCount += cnt;
}

if (!map.isEmpty()) {
  message.addHeader(TEMPLATE_MERGEVARS_HEADER, BINDER.writeValue(map));
}

private static int charCount(Entry<String, String> e) {
  return e.getKey().length() + e.getValue().length() + 6;
}
```

message will contain all the header values as multi-map.